# How to update chart when data is changing?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, onchange

I have two columns were is information that I use in chart and it is changing according to what time range I choose. The main problem is that the columns length can be different, it can be 5 rows and when I choose another period of time it can be 7 rows or less then 5. The data in chart is refreshing, but the number of columns not, e.g. I have data like this:

```
 Tom 20
 Susan 30
 John 15
```

So the chart would have three columns and their color is different according to the value in the first column, but when I choose another period of time data changes to:

```
 Peter 40
 Patrick 70
 Joe 36
 Megan 57
 Susan 74
```

Now the chart will contain three columns with only the first three names: Peter, Patrick, Joe and the color of columns will be the same as in the first chart.

I hope it is easy to understand my problem, the main thing is that the visualization of the chart doesn't change as it's supposed to. I add a part of my code:

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim MyRangex As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ChartRange1 As Range

    LastRow = Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row

    Set MyRangex = Worksheets("Calculate").Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    Set ChartRange1 = Sheets("Calculate").Range("G2:G" & LastRow)

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = MyRangex
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = ChartRange1

    For i = 1 To Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(9, 10).value
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i).Select
        Select Case Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(i + 1, 5).value
            Case Is = "Tom"
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            Case Is = "Susan"
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            Case Is = "Joe"
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
            Case Is = "John"
                With Selection.Format.Fill
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                    .Transparency = 0
                    .Solid
                End With
        End Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: May I ask, how do you choose the period? Is there some specific cell where you input a new period? Or is there some kind of macro associated with a control which updates info in the sheet "Calculate"? What is that control?

Comment: There is another worksheet with all information, where you can choose time period from which data is selected. Then in worksheet "Calculate" some information is calculated, e.g how many times every person went to the store, if he didn't visit that store at that period of time he isn't in the list, so that list is changing. Everything is done with a lot of code...

Comment: is the data always in the same column(s), just with different amounts of rows, depending on the time period?

Comment: yes, that's right. And ZygD already helped me,everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should employ a `Worksheet_Change` event. It must reside in the worksheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("C2"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "data in C2 was changed"
    End If
End Sub
```

The `MsgBox` in this example appears only when data in the cell `C2` is changed. Depending on how you change your new period, this part should be changed.

---

No matter if you update your period manually or automatically, I am sure the code below will work for you. (Unless there are formulas under these names.)

Requirements for usage:
**1.** Place this code inside your **worksheet** module (not a regular module which appears after you record a macro).
**2.** Rename your chart to "MyChartName" OR **replace this name in the code with your actual chart name**.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim MyRangex As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ChartRange1 As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim mySeries As Series

    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("E2:E100"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        LastRow = Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

        Set MyRangex = Worksheets("Calculate").Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
        Set ChartRange1 = Sheets("Calculate").Range("G2:G" & LastRow)
        Set mySeries = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChartName").Chart.SeriesCollection(1)

        mySeries.XValues = MyRangex
        mySeries.Values = ChartRange1

        For i = 1 To Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(9, 10).Value
            With mySeries.Points(i).Format.Fill
                Select Case Worksheets("Calculate").Cells(i + 1, 5).Value
                    Case Is = "Tom"
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        .Transparency = 0
                        .Solid
                    Case Is = "Susan"
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 240)
                        .Transparency = 0
                        .Solid
                    Case Is = "Joe"
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        .Transparency = 0
                        .Solid
                    Case Is = "John"
                        .Visible = msoTrue
                        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(191, 191, 191)
                        .Transparency = 0
                        .Solid
                End Select
            End With
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @MiglėPapuškaitė - I incorporated your code into the `Worksheet_Change ` event. Please try again now. I also did some small optimisation.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.